# SSRS: Setting the bottom border based on the grouping

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I would like to apply a bottom border to my report based on the first group

I have 3 groups: 
Parent: Region
Child 1: City
Child 2: Area

I want the border applied to the bottom on the last row of the group, based on the parent group: Region.

I am currently trying this (In the Top option of border style) but it is not working perfectly

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!Region.Value, CountDistinct, "Region") MOD 2 = 1,"Solid", Nothing)
```

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this without using an expression.

- I added a parent group in the row group
- Selected the option 'Add group footer'
- Highlighted the bottom row and set the border style (bottom) to 'solid'

That does it!